# How to display arabic keyboard or arabic input for particular UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, arabic, arabic-support

I have 2 `UITextField`s, first is for description in english and another is for description in Arabic. My app has localisation, but irrespective of that localisation, I need display english keyboard for english description textfield and arabic keyboard for arabic textfield. Can you guys help me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

That's a `UITextFieldDelegate` method, so you need to make your View Controller conform to it. The example with English alphabet:

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if !["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"].contains(string.lowercased()) {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Remember to set your textfield's delegate to `self` (your ViewController):

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    engTextField.delegate = self
}
```

UPD: May be it's better to use `!Array("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm").contains(string.lowercased())`